# I love you guys... but what's this about?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

I went to https://stackexchange.com/ to see what was there and whats changed.

[image: Stack Exchange front page]

And so I click Learn More... which takes me to https://stackexchange.com/about

[image: Stack Exchange about page]

And there's Joel glaring, and Jeff being very happy... and David looking not angry.  But this really doesn't tell me what Stack Exchange is ***about*** or any bit about how to learn more about Stack Exchange.

I was kind of expecting a tour of the site... not the staff.

Consider linking 'Learn more' to https://stackexchange.com/tour instead.

Comment: That's... an oversight. Things moved around recently, and yeah, the button should probably point elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, and we love you too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's been fixed and is currently on our dev server. Will push out to production soonish (after some unrelated bug is fixed).

Thanks for reporting!