# The SE About page should be less Stack Overflow-focused: "The world’s largest programming community is growing"

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com, site-promotion

As of April 9, 2023 https://stackexchange.com/about shows the following text

> The world’s largest programming community is growing

[image: About - Stack Exchange as of April 9, 2023]

There is no doubt that **programming** is the specific topic of the first site, Stack Overflow, and from which the company takes its current name (for advertising / marketing purposes), but "largest programming community" doesn't match **Stack Exchange**.

From the https://stackexchange.com/tour

> **Stack Exchange** is a network of 180 communities that are created and run by experts and enthusiasts like you who are passionate about a specific topic. We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on each community's area of expertise.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange)

> **Stack Exchange** is a network of [question-and-answer (Q&A)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_and_answer_website) [websites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website) on topics in diverse fields, each site covering a specific topic, where questions, answers, and users are subject to a reputation award process.

I know the tour and Wikipedia have different purposes. The text in the About page might be the "elevator pitch," "tagline," "motto," or another text that advertising experts recommended as the first statement in a page like this.

I'm not good at writing in English, or [copywriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copywriting) in my mother tongue either, so please excuse me that I don't provide a better suggestion than the Wikipedia quote, and report this as a bug instead of a feature request.

---

The title might have sense in 2015, as the first statement of the following paragraph at that time said ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150121094622/http://stackexchange.com/about))

> Stack Exchange is the largest network of websites for software developers including Stack Overflow, the pre-eminent destination site for programmers to find, ask, and answer their questions.

but nowadays the first statement of the following paragraph says:

> Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network help people find the answers they need, when they need them.

Even the rest of the paragraph doesn't mention programmers or developers.

---

I found another description that might be interesting. From [Ask technical questions on Stack Exchange | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/stackexchange)

> Stack Exchange is a large community of fellow enthusiasts, motivated by the desire for [Stack Exchange reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), who are likely to provide a great answer.

---

I found this while contuining my adventure [down the rabbit hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_the_rabbit_hole).

### Related

- [About pages should be about the specific StackExchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187137/289691)
- [I love you guys... but what's this about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235190/289691)
- [The whole SE is now a programming community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252356/289691)
- [Some questions regarding SE network statistics on about page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292581/289691)

Comment: In a comment it was mentioned that this have this way since years ago. The oldest version archived of this page having "The world’s largest programming
community is growing" is from [January 21, 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150121094622/http://stackexchange.com/about). Apparently the change occurred after [I love you guys... but what's this about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235190/289691).

Comment: Apparently according to Adam Lear (staff) this is by design, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/252356/revisions.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you very much. You have removed from myself the stigma of being the first one that have seen this in many years :D

Answer (score 12):

I think this is an excellent idea.

Despite the validity of Glorfindel's counter(?)-argument(s), I think an edit would make sense.

I'm not a programmer. I program at times, but I signed up when I started to get interested in the video gaming SE site, and my activity on SO and [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) is relatively nonexistent. I also signed up through [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) (I *think*), or another non-programmers sister site, as I'm sure many (even though it could be *relatively* few) users do.

I also believe that the fact that not many stumble upon the SE *About* page is a weak argument against changing it, especially on a platform that promotes improving anything that is of low quality.

Finally, if we want to take ourselves seriously as a platform offering information about more than the spectrum of digital arts, this request should be taken into serious consideration.

Comment: I do hope this doesn't escalate into an argument between programmers and non-programmers, though 

Answer (score 6):

I distinctly remember (and can't find) an old interview or blog post that basically talked about how the network was basically built around developers and the other sites were interests they had.

SE has much broader reach and discoverability from those days.

I do believe there was an initiative at [the start of Prasanth's tenure as CEO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/24/announcing-stack-overflows-new-ceo-prashanth-chandrasekar/) to include knowledge workers in general, but I'm not entirely sure what happened to it.

While SE being a developer/knowledge worker/techie community primarily is true to an extent - sometimes *some* old ways ought to go. SE's a platform that works very well, and we've a ton of users who are not developers, *or* technical folks who have thrived here. Some folks are even moderators.

And potentially it may not be true - are we bigger than GitHub? We are however, through the efforts of our community an influential (enough that people keep complaining :D) and useful, high quality source of information. Posts are peer reviewed and in a healthy community curated and maintained. We're the leading *Q&A* site on the Internet as much as anything else.

As such, I feel like this needs a rethink.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is more truth in this statement than you (probably) realize. The influence of Stack Overflow is so big that a large part of many (if not all) communities (say, Cooking Stack Exchange) isn't formed by experts on cooking (chefs, home bakers) but rather *programmers* who are also an expert (or at least enthusiast) in cooking. Conversely, that specific topic may have a Q&A site which is way more popular than the Stack Exchange site and have a more 'typical' user base.

So in that sense, it's really a programming community (but interested in many different topics) with the welcome addition of other valuable members :)

Comment: I agree that the influece of people that participate in Stack Overflow is strong here and in many sites, specially during the site proposal process but I don't think that promoting Stack Exchange as a community of programmers make good. It's like saying that people that has a SO account can't stop thinking and behave as programmer in other contexts. It will be a warning sign to people willing to join that they will be having to deal with "programmers" all the time.

Comment: If all you ever visit is Cooking.SE, you won't see that page ...

Comment: And that is relevant in this context because...

Comment: you're asking something about a page nobody visits except Stack Exchange network experts? stackexchange.com isn't that discoverable, you're most likely to get there if you're interested in the network, which further increases the chance you're a programmer :)

Comment: I think that you are deviating to what was said in the answer. Actually the answer doesn't look to disagree with changing the referred stamentement in https://stackexchange.com/about. I'm not sure what is the point of the last comment. Are you saying that do you not want that "The world’s largest programming community is growing" be changed in any way? Is your argument to not change this statement that only programmers are able to find this page? P.S. I'm not a programmer :)

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't need to be changed - just offering some additional explanation why it is as it is, and why that (IMHO) isn't a big deal.

Comment: Regarding priorities, I agree that there might be other things that migh me more urgent and important, but I think that this should be between the important things.

Comment: It's not urgent - it's been like that for years, and you're the first person to notice it :) I tried to explain why it's not that important, but I do understand why it matters to you.

Comment: I'm not sure how should I understand that. Please explain.

Comment: I was not the first to notice this :) h/t [Marijin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388208/the-se-about-page-should-be-less-stack-overflow-focused-the-world-s-largest-pr#comment1294349_388208)